# In triangle $ABC$, $G$ is the centroid, $I$ is the incenter, $GI$ || $BC$. What is $\frac{AB+AC}{BC}$?

Tags: geometry, triangles, centroid

> In triangle $ABC$, $G$ is the centroid, $I$ is the incenter, $GI$ ||
> $BC$, what is $\frac{AB+AC}{BC}$?

I have little to no idea what to do with this problem. I drew the diagram and called the point where the angle bisector of $B$ and the median from $C$ intersect $P$, so $\triangle PGI$ is similar to $\triangle PCB$. Additionally, since medians split each other into $2:1$ ratios, I have that $GC:GD$ (where $D$ is the midpoint of $AB$)is $2:1@. But that's about all I have.

I need a bit of help.

Comment: If $r$ is the inradius, $h$ is the height from $A$, $a$ is the length of $BC$, and $s$ the semi-perimeter, then $h=3r$ and $\frac12 ha=rs$.

Comment: Interestingly, the loci of $G$ and $I$ are tangent ellipses with the same center $M$ and the same axes of symmetry, where $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$.  The minor axes $TT'$ of the two ellipses are identical, where $T$ and $T'$ are the centroids of the equilateral triangles with side $BC$.  The major axis of the locus of $I$ is $BC$ itself.  The major axis of the locus of $G$ is $B'C'$ where $B'$ and $C'$ are internal points of $BC$ such that $BB'=\frac{BC}{6}=C'C$.

Comment: (In the comment above, $B$ and $C$ are fixed, but $A$ varies.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of the triangle is

$$Area_{ABC} = \frac12 h BC = \frac 12 r (AB+AC+BC)\tag 1$$

where $h$ is the altitude from A to BC and $r$ is the incircle radius.

Since G is the centroid, the distance from G to BC is one-third of $h$, which happens to be $r$ because $I$ and $G$ are at the same height, i.e. $h=3r$. Plug into (1) to obtain
$3BC = AB+AC+BC$, or

$$\frac{AB+AC}{BC}=2$$